# Variáveis globais recursão

Tags: c, recursão

Estou aprendendo recursão e tenho dúvidas quanto a utilização de variáveis globais, particularmente acho <strike>uma gambiarra</strike> deselegante, talvez possa estar enganado. Fiz um código para somar números positivos e utilizei uma variável chamada soma. Gostaria de saber se há outras saídas para essa questão. Código abaixo:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int soma = 0;

int SomaPositivos(int vet[], int n)  {
    if (n == 0) {
      return 0;
    } else { 
        int aux;
        if (vet[n-1] > 0) {     
            aux = vet[n-1];
            soma = soma + aux;
            SomaPositivos(vet, n-1);
        }
    }

    return soma;
}

int main () {   
    int v[20] = {2, 1, 8, 3, 4};
    int a;

    a = SomaPositivos(v, 5);
    printf("%d ", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em relação a recursividade não sei dizer se é "adequado" usar variáveis globais, ainda mais no seu caso, existem outras formas de somar os positivos do vetor sem ter que utilizar a variável global `soma`, eu particularmente preferia não utilizar.

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872959/5429980) afirma que variáveis globais podem gerar conflitos quando esta trabalhando com threads, e isso faz sentido mesmo, eu não usaria neste cenário, ninguém tem controle dela.

Fiz uma adaptação da sua função com base neste [algoritmo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15801992/5429980), veja:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int SomaPositivos (int vet[], int n, int soma)
{
    if (n < 0)
    {
        return soma;
    }
    else
    {
        if (vet[n] > 0)
            soma += vet[n];
    }

    return SomaPositivos(vet, --n, soma);
}

int main(void)
{
    int v[20] = {-1, 2, 1, 8, 3, 4, -12};
    int a;
    int soma = 0;

    a = SomaPositivos (v, 7, soma);
    printf ("%d ", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Saída

> 18

Answer (score 4):

Uma alternativa possível é utilizar um parâmetro acumulador:

```
int somaPositivos(int soma, int vet[], int n)  {
    int somaAteAqui = soma;
    if (n <= 0) {
      return soma;
    } else { 
        int aux = vet[n-1];
        if (aux > 0) {   
            somaAteAqui += aux;
        }    
        somaAteAqui = somaPositivos(somaAteAqui, vet, n - 1);
    }

    return somaAteAqui;
}
```

Chamada de exemplo:

```
int resultado = somaPositivos(0, vet, 5);
```

Answer (score 4):

Não precisa utilizar a variável `int soma`, só um ajuste na lógica da sua função recursiva para somar somente os valores que são ***positivos***:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int SomaPositivos(int vet[], int n)  
{
    if (n >= 0)
    {
        return (vet[n-1] > 0 ? vet[n-1] : 0) + SomaPositivos(vet, (n-1));
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(void) 
{
    int v[20] = {2, 1, 8, 3, 4, -6};
    int a;

    a = SomaPositivos(v, 6);
    printf("%d ", a);

    return 0;
}
```

*Exemplo:* [***Online***](http://ideone.com/G3Ks7P)

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [Exemplo de código usando Recursão](http://www.cprogressivo.net/2013/03/O-que-sao-e-como-usar-funcoes-recursivas-em-linguagem-C.html)
- [Recursividade em C](http://linguagemc.com.br/recursividade-em-c/)